# Powershell dsacls on success or fail

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have PowerShell script which delegates powers of security group for the selected OU via dsacls.
All works fine but i want to output a JSON response for success delegation (without all dsacls access list and object info) and for error just information.

How i run dcals:

```
dsacls "OU=Organization,DC=domain,DC=tld" /I:S /G GroupName:RPWP;sn;user
```

How to check now is dsacls run correct delegate and return via ConvertTo-Json method?

Is there another option than checking response string of dsacls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
$res = dsacls "OU=Organization,DC=domain,DC=tld" /I:S /G GroupName:RPWP;sn;user

@{ success = $?
   error = if (!$?) { [string]$res } else { "" }
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

the `$?` variable contains the success status of the last executed command (`true` or `false`)

Comment: Thank you. This is enough for me.